# Register receivers, start services on App install doesn't work

Tags: android

I have an Application that starts running as soon as it is installed, i.e. the BroadcastReceivers and Services are register as soon as the Application is installed on the handset. I've removed the action MAIN and category LAUNCHER from the main Activity class. This used to work in the Android OS systems prior to 4.0. 
But on the Operating Systems 4.0 and above, I'm having to open the main UI/Activity screen at least once after the Application is installed on the handset. Is there something Google changed with regards to their policies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of android 3.1 you need to start the application at least once before the BOOT_COMPLETED intent is launched (I am assuming that is what you are doing). Look at this [link](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a bit of a disappointment but can understand why Google did it